# How do I categorize my website (domain)?

Tags: seo, domains, web-hosting, url, dns-servers

I recently purchased a domain and created the website. I found that this belongs to "None" category and so found blocked in cyberoam firewall.

[image]

I tried with all possible meta tags at index.html. But any content from this domain is blocked (otherwise can say categorized NONE). The image's url is also blocked

---

In Godaddy I can find only "Auto-Renew, Lock, Nameservers, Forwarding, Premium DNS, DS Records, Host Names, Authorization Code" features to customize.

And Some Upgrade features like "Privacy, Domain Ownership Protection, Certified Domain , Premium Listing, CashParking, GoDaddy Auctions, SSL Certificate, Business Registration, Domain Appraisal".

Please help me where / how to categorize my domain as "Personal"?

Is anything needs to be changed in robots.txt?

Comment: The other post is not an answer to this question. Sadly I am stumped by the same problem.